# How to get extreme leaf node against heights parent in self referencing linq

Tags: c#, linq

I having the data structure

```
-Emp1 - Emp1_1 - Emp1_1_1
               - Emp1_1_2
      - Emp1_2 - Emp1_2_1
               - Emp1_2_2
-Emp2 - Emp2_1 - Emp2_1_1
               - Emp2_1_2
      - Emp2_2 - Emp2_2_1
               - Emp2_2_2
```

I want a dictionary which hold extreme leaf node as key and its highest parent as value.
OP:

(Emp1_1_1, Emp1)
(Emp1_1_2, Emp1) 
(Emp1_2_1, Emp1)
(Emp1_2_2, Emp1)
(Emp2_1_1, Emp2)
(Emp2_1_2, Emp2)
(Emp2_2_1, Emp2)
(Emp2_2_2, Emp2)

```
(Emp1_1_1, Emp1)
(Emp1_1_2, Emp1) 
(Emp1_2_1, Emp1)
(Emp1_2_2, Emp1)
(Emp2_1_1, Emp2)
(Emp2_1_2, Emp2)
(Emp2_2_1, Emp2)
(Emp2_2_2, Emp2)
```

Below is c# code

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var program = new Program();
            var empList = program.GetData();
           //Some linq which return the expected dictionary.
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public class Employee
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int parentEmployee { get; set; }
            public List<Employee> childList { get; set; }
        }

        List<Employee> GetData()
        {
            var empList = new List<Employee>();

            var emp1 = new Employee() { Id = 1, Name = "Emp1_Name", childList = new List<Employee>() };
            var emp1_1 = new Employee() { Id = 2, Name = "Emp1_1_Name", parentEmployee = emp1.Id, childList = new List<Employee>() };
            var emp1_2 = new Employee() { Id = 3, Name = "Emp1_2_Name", parentEmployee = emp1.Id, childList = new List<Employee>() };
            emp1.childList.Add(emp1_1);
            emp1.childList.Add(emp1_2);
            var emp1_1_1 = new Employee() { Id = 4, Name = "Emp1_1_1_Name", parentEmployee = emp1_1.Id };
            var emp1_1_2 = new Employee() { Id = 5, Name = "Emp1_1_2_Name", parentEmployee = emp1_1.Id };
            emp1_1.childList.Add(emp1_1_1);
            emp1_1.childList.Add(emp1_1_2);
            var emp1_2_1 = new Employee() { Id = 6, Name = "Emp1_2_1_Name", parentEmployee = emp1_2.Id };
            var emp1_2_2 = new Employee() { Id = 7, Name = "Emp1_2_2_Name", parentEmployee = emp1_2.Id };
            emp1_2.childList.Add(emp1_2_1);
            emp1_2.childList.Add(emp1_2_2);



            var emp2 = new Employee() { Id = 1, Name = "emp2_Name", childList = new List<Employee>() };
            var emp2_1 = new Employee() { Id = 2, Name = "emp2_1_Name", parentEmployee = emp2.Id, childList = new List<Employee>() };
            var emp2_2 = new Employee() { Id = 3, Name = "emp2_2_Name", parentEmployee = emp2.Id, childList = new List<Employee>() };
            emp2.childList.Add(emp2_1);
            emp2.childList.Add(emp2_2);
            var emp2_1_1 = new Employee() { Id = 4, Name = "emp2_1_1_Name", parentEmployee = emp2_1.Id };
            var emp2_1_2 = new Employee() { Id = 5, Name = "emp2_1_2_Name", parentEmployee = emp2_1.Id };
            emp2_1.childList.Add(emp2_1_1);
            emp2_1.childList.Add(emp2_1_2);
            var emp2_2_1 = new Employee() { Id = 6, Name = "emp2_2_1_Name", parentEmployee = emp2_2.Id };
            var emp2_2_2 = new Employee() { Id = 7, Name = "emp2_2_2_Name", parentEmployee = emp2_2.Id };
            emp2_2.childList.Add(emp2_2_1);
            emp2_2.childList.Add(emp2_2_2);

            empList.Add(emp1);
            empList.Add(emp2);
            return empList;
        }
    }
```

I tried some solution like calling private self referencing function in linq,
But it works for a one parent - one child relation.

Comment: Use recursive linq can solve this quickly although the performance may not be the best (but we don't always need the fastest algorithm, when it comes to simple and easy to implement, we can take its benefit in many scenarios). https://dotnetfiddle.net/9LS1yG

Answer (score 1):

If the use of a recursive function is acceptable:

```
        Func<IEnumerable<Employee>, IEnumerable<Employee>> flatten = null;
        flatten = (IEnumerable<Employee> employees) => 
            employees.SelectMany(c => c.childList != null ? flatten(c.childList) : Enumerable.Empty<Employee>()).Concat(employees);

        var dict = (
            from topNode in empList
                    from node in flatten(topNode.childList)
                    where node.childList == null || node.childList.Count == 0
                    select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(node.Name, topNode.Name)
            ).ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);


        foreach(var keyValuePair in dict)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Key={keyValuePair.Key}, Value={keyValuePair.Value}");
        }
```

This outputs:

```
Key=Emp1_1_1_Name, Value=Emp1_Name
Key=Emp1_1_2_Name, Value=Emp1_Name
Key=Emp1_2_1_Name, Value=Emp1_Name
Key=Emp1_2_2_Name, Value=Emp1_Name
Key=emp2_1_1_Name, Value=emp2_Name
Key=emp2_1_2_Name, Value=emp2_Name
Key=emp2_2_1_Name, Value=emp2_Name
Key=emp2_2_2_Name, Value=emp2_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public static void Main()
{
    var program = new Program();
    var empList = program.GetData();

    Func<IEnumerable<Employee>, Employee, Dictionary<Employee, Employee>> TreeToDict = null;
    TreeToDict = (employees, topParent) => 
    employees.SelectMany(e => 
                         {
                             if(e.childList != null)
                             {
                                 return TreeToDict(e.childList, topParent == null ? e : topParent);
                             }
                             else
                             {
                                 Dictionary<Employee, Employee> dict = new Dictionary<Employee, Employee>();
                                 dict.Add(e, topParent == null ? e : topParent);
                                 return dict;
                             }

                         }).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

    foreach(var emp in TreeToDict (empList, null))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("key : {0}, value {1}", emp.Key.Name, emp.Value.Name);
    }
}
```

result

```
key : Emp1_1_1_Name, value Emp1_Name
key : Emp1_1_2_Name, value Emp1_Name
key : Emp1_2_1_Name, value Emp1_Name
key : Emp1_2_2_Name, value Emp1_Name
key : emp2_1_1_Name, value emp2_Name
key : emp2_1_2_Name, value emp2_Name
key : emp2_2_1_Name, value emp2_Name
key : emp2_2_2_Name, value emp2_Name
```